# How to work with html frames in Django

Tags: html, django, frames

I start using the Django to build up a webpage. What I expected is the following:

I might have two frames, left and right. I have a search form in left frame. What I expected is that after I input the search key word, the search results will render at the right frame.

If, I only consider page with only one frame with search form, and after I submit search keyword, the search results will render in the same page.  This might easy just by let render_to_response to display the correct template page.

However, when I have two frames as I described before, I did not find some thing to render the coorect template page on the specified target ( the right frames ).

Or maybe a more vague problem, suppose we have two frames on one page, I have a referesh button on one (left) frames, is there any way,when I click it, I get two frames get refreshed ?

Comment: frames are so last century... current trends are ajax and pjax (pushState + ajax).

Comment: pjax is now 'unmaintained': https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to work with html frames in Django

Frames are a client side technology. Django doesn't make a difference.

> However, when I have two frames as I described before, I did not find some thing to render the coorect template page on the specified target

```
<form ... target="name_of_frame">
```

> Or maybe a more vague problem, suppose we have two frames on one page, I have a referesh button on one (left) frames, is there any way,when I click it, I get two frames get refreshed ?

That would involve JavaScript (assuming you want to refresh the current representation of each frame).

---

Frames are a problematic technology and (other than iframes) do not exist in HTML 5.

Most uses of frames are better replaced with single pages where shared content (e.g. the form in the above example) is duplicated (this can be done using Django templates) and layout is handled by CSS.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your response are very helpful. I might try to follow your suggestion to avoid using the frames.